# How to get the value in Python list？

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

['time=139', 'time=102', 'time=120', 'time=105', 'time=116', 'time=183', 'time=153', 'time=100', 'time=151', 'time=123', 'time=155', 'time=135']

how to get only number from these list?

I tried to get the value from this list, I don't how to just get the number?

Comment: Look into `string.split()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split()` and get the value after `=` sign.

```
numbers = [int(string.split('=')[1]) for string in ['time=139', 'time=102', 'time=120', 'time=105', 'time=116', 'time=183', 'time=153', 'time=100', 'time=151', 'time=123', 'time=155', 'time=135']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from re import split
lst=['time=139', 'time=102', 'time=120', 'time=105', 'time=116', 'time=183', 'time=153', 'time=100', 'time=151', 'time=123', 'time=155', 'time=135']
string="".join(lst)
A=split("time=",string) #splited buy "time="
lst=A[1:]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score -3):

Fetch while iterating over a list and write values to a new list or convert to a dictionary to user in further code.

Sample code:

```
a_lst = ['time=139', 'time=102', 'time=120', 'time=105', 'time=116', 'time=183', 'time=153', 'time=100', 'time=151', 'time=123', 'time=155', 'time=135']
a_values = []
for item in a_lst:
    a_values.append(int(item.split("=")[1]))
print(a_values)
```

List comprehension way:

```
a_values = [ int(item.split("=")[1]) for item in a_lst]
```

Comment: don't use `.append` in your list comprehension. Now `a_values` is a list of all `None`s. List comprehensions are *not for side-effects*. They are *functional, mapping/filtering operations*

Comment: oops, yes you are correct, It's copy - paste mistake